# sql query to bring back multiple results

Tags: sql

I have a database table with the following columns

```
 Id    ReviewStreamTypeId    ReviewerTitleTypeId     ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber
 1             1                      1                           1
 2             1                      27                          2
 3             1                      9                           3
 4             2                      1                           1
 5             2                      27                          2 
 6             2                      10                          3
 7             3                      1                           1
 8             3                      16                          2
 9             3                      24                          3
```

I'm trying to write a query that gets all of the ReviewStreamTypeId where ReviewerTitleTypeId = 1 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 1 and ReviewerTitleTypeId = 27 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 2.  So I'm looking for the result set 1,2

This is the query I wrote, which doesn't work

```
 select ReviewStreamTypeId 
 from Routing.ReviewStreamReviewerOrder 
 where (ReviewerTitleTypeId = 1 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 1) 
 and (ReviewerTitleTypeId = 27 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 2 )
```

Any ideas on how to write the query to bring back the right results?

Comment: "`where ReviewerTitleTypeId = 1 ... and ReviewerTitleTypeId = 27`" Can never happen.

Comment: Are you sure it is "and" not "or" for the ReviewerTitleTypeId =1 and ReviewerTitleTypeId = 27??

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes that can happen... over multiple rows.. look at the data set.. multiple ReviewerTitleTypeId for a ReviewStreamTypeId.. he wants the ReviewerTitleTypeId = 1 and =27 for each ReviewStreamTypeId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
 select ReviewStreamTypeId 
 from Routing.ReviewStreamReviewerOrder 
 group by ReviewStreamTypeId
 having sum(case when ReviewerTitleTypeId = 1 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
        sum(case when ReviewerTitleTypeId = 27 and ReviewStreamReviewerOrderNumber = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```